# TableTools Hidden columns genereated in save as Excel option

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have implemented TableTools in Datatables. I have some hidden columns in the browser but when i generate excel. It is generating with those hidden columns. But These hidden columns should not be included in generate excel too. How can i do this.

Answer (score 5):

Use [mColumns](http://datatables.net/extras/tabletools/button_options#mColumns). It determines which fields to use in the Export.

```
$(document).ready( function () {
    $('#example').dataTable( {
        "sDom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
        "oTableTools": {
            "aButtons": [
                {
                    "sExtends": "ajax",
                    "sButtonText": "Special columns",
                    "mColumns": [ 0, 1, 4 ]
                },
                {
                    "sExtends": "ajax",
                    "sButtonText": "Visible columns",
                    "mColumns": "visible"
                }
            ]
        }
    } );
} );
```